# Is there a way to search just a particular drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I've used Windows 7 for a long time at home where I never need to search for anything.  But now that work has upgraded from XP to 7, I have no idea how to search one particularity drive.

Comment: Your workplace had XP till now? How did you even work?

Comment: @AwalGarg Not even moderately uncommon, sadly.

Comment: @Awal Garg, Neither Java nor PHP development requires Windows 7. For that matter C# works just fine with XP too, as long as you aren't coding for Silverlight or Sharepoint. I would have held out and not even upgraded to 7 yet if I weren't about to get into those two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Explorer (press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). Navigate to the root folder of the drive you want to search. In the top-right corner of the Explorer window, enter your search term and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Finally, wait until the results appear below.

Comment: Sorry, this is a bad to suggestion, doesnt work, and was the entire reason i landed here in the first place, how did this get the accepted answer, and the most points?  Frankly, ,windows searches all drives, atleast for me, when i do this.

Comment: @BrianThomas Absolutely not. Even the placeholder text in the search box indicates that Windows will only search the current element. You probably only selected the drive instead of opening it. You need to open the folder you want to search.

Comment: Hi, sorry then, but yeah it didnt work for me, and I of course opened the folder i wanted to search, i was searching the enitire C drive, but didn't realize how windows treats alternate drives, that even though aren't `system` have programs installed on it.  It not only searched `C`, it searched D, and `E` also which i have a backup on, no matter what i did, except for my answer.  HTH.  So it was making it entirely difficult to rule out of my `C` drive was clean for re-installation, since all my data was on `D`.

Answer (score 2):

I use Everything to search files on windows. Is faster than the one that comes integrated on the explorer.
If you choose to install everything the only thing you have to do is: "Right click" on the drive and then click on "Search with Everything..."

EDIT: [Download Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)

Comment: It may help to actually add a link to "everything" so people are downloading the correct software.

Comment: [I think downloading "everything" would take quite a bit of time...](http://www.gifbin.com/bin/1236166619_unzipping_the_internet.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I like the keyboard. So I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the run dialog, and type `cmd`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I then type `dir x:\filename.ext /s /a` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Replace the `x:` with whatever drive letter I want to search, and `filename.ext` with the file (or wildcard search) I want to find. The `/s` searches all subfolders, and the `/a` finds all file/folder types.

Comment: Downvote without comment? Really?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers on this page will work correctly, unless you install the 3rd party app, which also doesn't answer the OP question.

The way you search only one drive, is when you  open explorer to the drive you want, you still need to type in the drive letter, colon, and slash in the search box, and use an asterix if you need.

e.g. to find all pictured
`c:\*jpg`

If you do this `*.jpg`, even though you have clicked on the c drive before you search, it will still dig millions out of D,E, and so forth.

Comment: Norepro. The accepted answer works as I expect. If I go to C: and then simply search for (for example) "fish" I only get results on the C: drive. If I go to My Computer and search from there I get results from all drives. Are you sure you went *into* the C: drive rather than just selected it in My Computer? Could the asterisk be affecting the search? Are your drives fully indexed? (Mine are not)

Comment: I disagree, maybe on your system, if you search just for *.anything you will get it on all drives, especially if you have anything installed to an alternate drive, which alot of people do.  Now, this may or may not be the only case,   but trust me when i say the accepted answer didn't work, in fact it provided results from 3 drives, which is how i landed on this unhelpful post.  I added an answer that will work on more systems.

Comment: Hence why i was trying to work out *why* there is a difference. I didn't downvote because you could well be right,  but it would be good to know why it works this way for you.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for that, we all know what that feels like don't we?  I do, especially after great efforts on my part to avoid it.

Comment: Did you click on the c drive or double-click on the c drive?

Comment: I was in it(double clicked), looking at all the files of it(e.g. Program Files, Users, Windows, etc..), i was not looking at the drive list that one sees in my computer, i saw all the files in C, e.g. the files i wanted to be searching.  Very odd....  On reinstallation, im not having this issue either.  Even when i Do have backups and installs on D.